# docker build fails with access denied or repository not exist

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LetsKube.dll"]
```

While trying to execute the above its give an error

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

steps i tried :

1. Changed base to  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

How to solve this and build and image for aspnet 2.0 framework apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your referenced repos "microsoft/aspnetcore-build" and "microsoft/aspnetcore" are the problem here, since they don't exists/are available in the public docker hub.

You can check for available tags for .NET SDK [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/?tab=description).

You can check for available tags for .NET Runtime [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/).

You could try with something like this, according to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1.816-stretch AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

# build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.1.28-stretch-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LetsKube.dll"]
```

You could also start experimenting with the different images listed in the attached links, so you find what works better for you.

Comment: I tried your dockerbuild but its giving an error related with nuget , ~#9 35.33   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.2.0.3' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite/2.0.3/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.2.0.3.nupkg'.
#9 35.33    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
#9 35.33   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.2.0.3' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities/2.0.3/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.2.0.3.nupkg'.~

Comment: It might be something related specifically to your dependencies then. 
I tried creating a new asp net core 2 project and creating the image with the dockerfile I wrote.
Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Does your project restore fine in your IDE? I just tried adding the reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.2.0.3  package and still no problems building the docker image. 
Maybe there is a connection issue with nuget?